# How to display Vertical Cover Flow in android

Tags: coverflow

I want to implement vertical cover flow in my application .I have source code of CoverFlow but it showing horizontal way.I have made some changes in code and apply this method imageView.setRotation(270) after that it shows vertical mode but one problem is that it is showing only one images in center of cover flow,but it is not looking like Cover Flow.Can any one tell me where do i needed changes in my code for looking vertical CoverFlow.Your help is really appreciated.I attaching source code here

```
 public class AllDeals extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener 
{

     CoverFlow cover;
     Button btn_back,btn_up,btn_down,btn_more;
     TextView txt_cardesc,txt_carprize,txt_vat;
     public   int myposition=-1;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alldeals, container,false);
        cover=(CoverFlow)v.findViewById(R.id.alldeal_cover);

        btn_back=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_alldeal_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_up=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_alldeals_up);
        btn_down=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_all_deal_down);

        btn_more=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_all_deal_more);

        // for text views
        txt_cardesc=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_cardesc);
        txt_carprize=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_alldeal_carprize);
        txt_vat=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_alldeal_vat);



        // add set action listener to buttons 

        btn_up.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_down.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_more.setOnClickListener(this);



        cover.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());

        cover.setSpacing(-5);
        cover.setSelection(-1, true);
        cover.setAnimationDuration(1000);
        cover.setRotation(90);

        //set up listener for cover
        setListener(cover);

        return v;

    }
    private void setListener(CoverFlow myCoverFlow)
   {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myposition=position;
            }

        });
        myCoverFlow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myposition=position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }
    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02,
                R.drawable.image03, R.drawable.image04, R.drawable.image05 };

        private ImageView[] mImages;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean createReflectedImages() {
            // The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
            final int reflectionGap = 4;

            int index = 0;
            for (int imageId : mImageIds) {
                Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), imageId);
                int width = originalImage.getWidth();
                int height = originalImage.getHeight();

                // This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.preScale(1, -1);

                // Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
                // We only want the bottom half of the image
                Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
                        height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

                // Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit
                // reflection
                Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                        (height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);

                // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
                // the image plus gap plus reflection
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
                // Draw in the original image
                canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
                // Draw in the gap
                Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap,
                        deafaultPaint);
                // Draw in the reflection
                canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap,
                        null);

                // Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the
                // reflection
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
                        originalImage.getHeight(), 0,
                        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap,
                        0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
                // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
                paint.setShader(shader);
                // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
                // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,
                        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
                android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams imgLayout = new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(
                        320, 480);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);
                imageView.setPadding(30, 100, 20, 20);
                mImages[index++] = imageView;

            }
            return true;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Use this code if you want to load from resources

            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(180, 240));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

            i.setRotation(270);

            // Make sure we set anti-aliasing otherwise we get jaggies
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable();
            drawable.setAntiAlias(true);
            return i;

            // return mImages[position];
        }

        /**
         * Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views depending on the
         * 'offset' to the center.
         */
        public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
            return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float) Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view==btn_back)
        {
            mActivity.pushFragments(com.media.contractcar.base.AppConstants.TAB_HOME, new Home(), true, true);
        }
        if(view==btn_up)
        {
            try
            {
            cover.setSelection(myposition+1,true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(view==btn_down)
        {
            if(myposition>0)
            {
                cover.setSelection(myposition-1,true);
            }

        }
    }

}
```